# For VBA loops. Macro Excel Program

Tags: vba, loops, excel, if-statement

I have problem with my project using VBA. I have this column that has thousands of rows.

And these columns have values like `0.05, 1.3` etc.. and it also has complicated values with greater than sign `<` like `<0.05, <0.02` which is my real problem. I want to use `If Else` or `Looping` for this solution. But I don't know how. I'm a beginner in VBA macro excel.

What I want to happen from these rows is if Macro detect a value that has < it will automatically be divided by 2 so I won't have complicated values to get the maximum and minimum value for these rows.

**Edit1:** Uploaded Image

[image: sample image]

I hope you get my point about this matter. Sorry for my english. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First in VBA use `If IsNumeric(Range) Then` to trap cases with "<" in the cell value, then `Range.Value = CDbl(Replace(Range.Value,"<",""))/2`, assuming overwriting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a faster way using `Autofilter`. Using `Autofilter` will ensure that you will not have to loop through every cell.

**Sample Screenshot**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range, fltrdRng As Range
    Dim LRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Get the last row of Col H where your data is
        LRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range("H1:H" & LRow)

        With rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=<*"
            Set fltrdRng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        If Not fltrdRng Is Nothing Then
            For Each aCell In fltrdRng.Cells
                If aCell.Row > LRow Then Exit For

                '~~> 8 is for Col H
                If aCell.Column = 8 Then
                    aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, "<", "")
                    aCell.Value = Val(Trim(aCell.Value)) / 2
                End If
            Next aCell
        End If
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that was fast answer, and that really works. Thank you so much @Siddhart Rout. It helps a lot. Also thank you to those who answered my question. I'm loving this site and people around here such a genius persons. God bless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this then:

```
Sub RemoveComplicatedValues()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim x

Set rng = Range("H2", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

For Each cel In rng
    If InStr(1, cel, "<") <> 0 Then
        x = CSng(Split(cel, "<")(UBound(Split(cel, "<"))))
        cel = x / 2
    End If
Next     
End Sub
```

You can also fully qualify your `Workbook` and `Sheet` if you want.
Hope this helps.